# Understanding "Could not evaluate protobuf implementation type" in linux - python scripts and how to hide or solve

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, protocol-buffers

I'm working on Debian 10 with Python 3.7.3 and pip 23.2.1. protobuf package is installed in version 4.24.1 (shown with pip list).

Everytime I execute a python script (maybe they use protobuf, how to know this?) I get the message

> Could not evaluate protobuf implementation type

What does it mean, do I have to change something? If yes, what can I change or check?

If not, how can I hide this message?

Regards, Daniel

Checking that protobuf is installed as pip package in latest version available

Comment: Please share the code that generates the error.

Comment: Does `python -c 0` also display the error?

Comment: @Cow I use wirepas python scripts, e.g.  
[class WirepasNetworkInterface](https://github.com/wirepas/wirepas-mqtt-library/blob/main/wirepas_mqtt_library/wirepas_network_interface.py#L18)  
from e.g. this script (import...)  
[example_data.py](https://github.com/wirepas/wirepas-mqtt-library/blob/main/examples/example_data.py#L31)\

@pts Unfortunately it doesn't help as well as `python3 -c 0`

Comment: Actually I found a hit in github in [wirepas-mesh library](https://github.com/wirepas/wirepas-mesh-messaging-python/blob/main/wirepas_mesh_messaging/__init__.py#L46) Do you have an idea which excpetion could occur?